# GameObject Follow cursor yet also follows enemies?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple character that follows the player's cursor. What I also want is for when the game object "enemy" appears the character then goes to that location to alert the player. Once the enemy is gone the character continues to follow the cursor like normal. Is there a reason why my script won't work. How else can I paraphrase it?

```
public class FollowCursor : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    void Update () 
    {
        //transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,8.75f));
        if (gameObject.FindWithTag == "Enemy") 
        {           
            GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").transform.position
        }
        if (gameObject.FindWithTag != "Enemy")
        {       
            transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,8.75f));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compile? FindWithTag is a method and not a property/field so how are you comparing it with a string?

Comment: Also, write `else` instead of `if (gameObject.FindWithTag != "Enemy")`. You might want to learn C# before trying to make a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `FindWithTag` correctly, as it is a method that takes a string as parameter you need to use it like this: 
`GameObject.FindwithTag("Something")` as stated in the [Unity scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)

Now to apply this to your code you would need to do the following to set your players position based on wether or not an enemy is found (assuming this script is on your actual player object):

```
if(GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy"))
{
    //If an enemy is found with the tag "Enemy", set the position of the object this script is attatched to to be the same as that of the found GameObject.
    transform.position = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").transform.position;
}
else
{
    //when no enemy with the tag "Enemy" is found, set this GameObject its position to the the same as that of the cursor
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,8.75f));
}
```

However this code will just snap your player instantly to the position of the found Enemy. If this is not the desired behaviour you could use a function like [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) instead to make the player move to it gradually.

This code also has room for optimisation as searching for a GameObject every update frame is not the ideal solution. But for now it should work.

Comment: Thank you @remy_rn is there also a way to specify the coordinate in lines `Gameobject.FindWithTag` to make the model appear overhead ?

Comment: `transform.position = GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy").transform.position;` this will set the player position in the enemy position.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to code coding all the function for you, I'm not pretty sure about the beavihour of your code, I understand a gameobject will be attached to the mouse position, so not really following....

```
Vector3 targetPosition;
public float step = 0.01f;
void Update()
{

//if there is any enemy "near"/close
//targetPosition = enemy.position; 
//else
//targetPosition = MouseInput;

transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition , step);
}
```

For the f you can use a [SphereCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) and from the enemies returned get the closest one.

Comment: Im still unsure how to use Vector3.Movetowards if no tag is stated in the function. Since the enemy is Instantiated I wanted to use findtag.

Comment: If you use findtag it will search for the first enemy that the unity finds in the scene. If you use a SphereCast you can find the closest enemy to your player and use MoveTowards for moving your player towards the target Position, by the way seems you have this issue fixed.